# Oracle right outer join

Tags: oracle, outer-join

I have a oracle sql where I do an outer join between the accounts table and payments table. I want to know how to execute the condition p.payment_status_code = 'R' only when there is a matching record in the payments table. For the rest, the condition should not be executed.

```
FROM
accounts a, payments p
WHERE (a.account_balance <= a.low_balance_level OR a.account_balance <= 0)
AND a.account_id = p.account_id(+)
AND p.payment_status_code = 'R'
```

Regards,
-Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM
accounts a, payments p
WHERE (a.account_balance <= a.low_balance_level OR a.account_balance <= 0)
AND a.account_id = p.account_id(+)

AND p.payment_status_code(+) = 'R'
                         ^^^
```

Comment: Schurik - Thanks. How do we check more than one value with the method u suggested?
e.g. AND p.payment_status_code(+) IN ('R', 'O') does not work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to show the results with `payment_status_code = 'R'`, right?  In that case why would you need to use outer join?  You could just use the traditional join.  What are you trying to do?

```
FROM
accounts a, payments p
WHERE (a.account_balance <= a.low_balance_level OR a.account_balance <= 0)
AND a.account_id = p.account_id
AND p.payment_status_code = 'R'
```

If you want to show the account info, even for those without payment then you would use a left outer join instead of right outer join

```
FROM
accounts a
left join payments p on a.account_id = p.account_id AND p.payment_status_code = 'R'
WHERE (a.account_balance <= a.low_balance_level OR a.account_balance <= 0)
```

Comment: Hi jmsia - I want to show the account info even for those without payment and the outer join I used does give me account info even without payment info.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM
accounts a, payments p
WHERE (a.account_balance <= a.low_balance_level OR a.account_balance <= 0)
AND a.account_id = p.account_id(+)
AND (p.account_id is null or p.payment_status_code = 'R')
```

Comment: RedFilter - Thanks for a quick response. Actually the payment_status_code can have null values too and I want only those records with 'R' code. Could you let me know we do it?

Comment: The query above should do what you ask. Perhaps post sample data and  desired output if it does not.